# MS Graph REST API checkout user

Tags: rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I've managed to successfully checkout a file using the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/checkout

**Now, I'd like to get the information about the user, who actually perform the checkout operation.**

It's possible to check if the item is locked: 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}?select=*,publication

However, according to DOCs, `publication` doesn't provide information about the checked user. Without information who locked the file is the whole checkin/checkout logic is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}` can't work with folders.

Anyway, `drive` endpoint "Allows access to the list as a drive" (according to MS Graph Docs). It works with folders as expected.

So I have

- get the drive-id: `/sites/${siteId}/drives`
- list root folder: `/drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children?select=name,publication`

if an item is locked, it's possible to list the `activity` on the item:

- `/drives/${idObj.driveId}/items/${idObj.fileId}?select=id&expand=activities`

return list of actions:

```
   "activities": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#oneDrive.activityEntity",
            "@odata.id": "https://xxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/oneDrive.activityEntity2a3649d6-2xxxxx",
            "@odata.editLink": "oneDrive.activityEntity2a3649d6xxxxxx",
            "@sharePoint.localizedRelativeTime": "0|July 30",
            "action": {
                "checkout": {}
            },
            "actor": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "XXX@XXX",
                    "displayName": "vladimir",
                    "self": {},
                    "userPrincipalName": "XXX@XXX
                }
            },
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "times": {
                "recordedTime": "2018-07-31T04:59:03Z"
            }
        },
```

although no user ID at least a have the email....

Answer (score 2):

This kind of information could be retrieved via [the metadata for an item in a list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/listItem_get) as demonstrated below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields(select=CheckoutUserLookupId)
```

Once you get *checkout user id* (`CheckoutUserLookupId` field) , user details could be determined via the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists('User Information List')/items/{CheckoutUserLookupId}
```

where `CheckoutUserLookupId` is the user id from the previous request

Comment: thank you, this helps a lot. However, this sites-list endpoint can't work with folders. so `list/{list-id}` gets all items, including the ones deep inside folders...